# Searching in db using Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to search and display specific data from db and the method that I have made is not retrieving data from database, if i print it just gives a empty array. 
My code is as follow:

**Controller:**

```
public function search() {

        $search = Input::get('search');
        if($search){
            $query = DB::table('volunteer');
            $results = $query ->where('bloodt', 'LIKE', $search) ->get();
            //print_r($results); exit;
            return View::make('search')->with("volunteer",$results);
        }  
}
```

**View:**

```
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'POST'))}}

<div class="pull-left col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-0">
    {{Form::text('search','',array('placeholder'=>'Search by blood type/zip code/address....','class'=>'form-control','required autofocus'))}}
</div>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
<br><br>
{{Form::close()}}

<?php if (isset($results)) { ?>
    @foreach($volunteer as $results)
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%; background-color: lightsteelblue">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>IC/Passport no.</th>
            <th>Blood Type</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Zip Code</th>
            <th>e-mail</th>
            <th>Phone no.</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $results->fname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->lname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->ic }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->bloodt }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->address }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->zipcode }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $results->phone }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        {{ $results->status }}
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Eligible</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Not Eligible</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    @endforeach
    <?php;
} ?>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('search', 'HomeController@search');
```

Comment: Did you get any data when used the print_r()?

Comment: No, i just get empty 'array()'.

Comment: Change your query to this: `$results = $query ->where('bloodt', 'LIKE', "%$search%") ->get();`

Comment: Still same. If print_r i got the array(), if not i will not get anything in my view.
I also tried before   $results = $query ->where('bloodt', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%') ->get();   but not working.

Comment: Can you `print_r($search)`?

Comment: Did you try to send your form to the controller method? In the `{{Form::open(array('method'=>'POST'))}}` add `'action' => 'HomeController@search'` or `'url' => 'search'` to the array

Comment: @aldrin27  i tried that and it seems that it was not getting the input because i named the button and the text-field same.

Comment: Can i see the updates?

Comment: @Daenu thank you for your reply, I paste it but still is not helping. However, the problem seems to be the  <?php if (isset($result))?> In my view. Without it is working just fine.

Comment: @aldrin27 I just change the button name from search to searchbutton and took out the <?php if (isset($result))?> from view than it show the data. Don't know why suddenly it does not pass the data from controller anymore and it says is undefined variable for $data.

Comment: Open the developers tab and go to network then request the data. What did you see?

Comment: @aldrin27, thank you for your replays. Now its working, don't know why but before it did not pass the data and now in the same way, just change variable name, and its working.

Comment: Okay. Have a good day.

Comment: @aldrin27 can you help me with this. 
       $status = Input::get('status');
        $id = Input::get('recordid');
     print_r($id);
    print_r($status);exit;
        $user = User::find($id);
       if (isset($status)){
            $user->status = $status;
            $user->save();
        }
        return View::make('search')->with('status',$status)
       
print_r output: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => Volunteer [1] => Volunteer [2] => Volunteer [3] => Eligible )
I want to save specific data for users but i dont know how to separate the array.